# Instant filter function with multiple filters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mongoose, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I would like to build a search function with several different filters. I have a RangeSlider component and function that give me the respective min max values. I save these filter values as objects and send them to the backend immediately each time a filter is changed.

Here I work with if, else conditions, which is certainly not the right way, but I didn't know what else to do and wanted to have at least a working prototype.

If you have one or two filters, this can still work, but not if you have many different ones. Furthermore, I wonder how to optimise the whole filtering process? With every request, the entire collection is searched. It would be great if the previous search query is applied to each new filter instead of searching through the entire collection again.

How can this be achieved?

[image]

**Frontend**
Every time a filter is updated `activeFilters` will be sent to the backend

```js
const activeFilters = reactive({ salePrice: '', space: '' })

async function updateFilter(minmax, property) {
  activeFilters[property] = minmax

  const filteredObjects = await $fetch('/api/properties/filtered', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: activeFilters,
  })

  return filteredObjects
}
```

**Backend**

body = { "salePrice": { "min": 630000, "max": 850948 }, "space": { "min": 53, "max": 167 } }

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const body = await readBody(event)

  try {
    if (body.salePrice !== '' && body.space !== '') {
      const properties = await Property.find({
        salePrice: { $gte: body.salePrice.min, $lte: body.salePrice.max },
        livableSurface: { $gte: body.space.min, $lte: body.space.max },
      })
      return properties
    }

    if (body.salePrice !== '') {
      const properties = await Property.find({
        salePrice: { $gte: body.salePrice.min, $lte: body.salePrice.max },
      })
      return properties
    }

    if (body.space !== '') {
      const properties = await Property.find({
        livableSurface: { $gte: body.space.min, $lte: body.space.max },
      })
      return properties
    }

    const properties = await Property.find()
    return properties
  } catch (err) {
    console.dir(err)
    event.res.statusCode = 500
    return {
      code: 'ERROR',
      message: 'Something went wrong.',
    }
  }
})
```

**Html**

```html
<InputsRangeSlider
  :config="salePriceSliderConfig"
  @updated-min-max="updateFilter($event, 'salePrice')"
/>

<InputsRangeSlider
  :config="spaceSliderConfig"
  @updated-min-max="updateFilter($event, 'space')"
/>
```

Comment: If you want an advanced and powerful search you will need to use tools like Algolia or ElastricSearch. Otherwise, you'll need to go hard on array methods like `filter`, `some`, etc... and make intersections, unions etc... No magic sauce regarding how to optimize it. There are maybe some packages that could help you achieve that but overall, pen + paper and some algorithms is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
const {salePrice, space} = body;
const conditions = {};

if (salePrice) conditions.salePrice = {$gte: salePrice.min, $lte: salePrice.max};
if (space) conditions.livableSurface = {$gte: space.min, $lte: space.max};

return Property.find(conditions);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a much cleaner solution!